# Standard practice to round values in ARM loans

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, quantitative, quants, banks

I have an application that calculates payments schedule of ARM (Adjustable Rate Mortgage) loans, where these loans are in the books of commercial banks.

It seems to work fine, with the exception of numbers that are incorrectly rounded. I compare my results with online calculators (where all of them provide the same results) and my application has 20 to 30 cents differences in balances and payments. An example of a calculator that I compare with is https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/arm-mortgage

Question: it seems there's a standard practice to round either interest rates, balances or payment amounts. What is this practice? In my application I don't perform any rounding .

Comment: this may be relevant: https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/Microsites/arrc/files/2020/ARRC_SOFR_Bilat_Loan_Conventions.pdf "It is recommended that interest-rate calculations based on SOFR be rounded (not truncated) to 5 decimal points and dollar amounts be rounded to 2 decimal points, for example, for any invoice or ledger reports, but that calculations not be rounded internally. " and https://selling-guide.fanniemae.com/Selling-Guide/Origination-thru-Closing/Subpart-B2-Eligibility/Chapter-B2-1-Mortgage-Eligibility/1116295391/How-is-the-fully-indexed-ARM-rate-calculated.htm